# Type with reference to itself - SML

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

I am new to SML and this style of programming, and I am having some issues. I have an assignment to do in ML, but I'm having some problems modeling the data. I solved the same problem in C, but I'm having problems doing so in SML/NJ. Here is what I want.

I have a struct in C which is like the following:

```
struct myStr {
    int someData;
    myOtherStruct someOtherData;
    struct myStr * next;
    struct myStr * prev;
}
```

The basic problem is that I sorted an array of pointers to `struct myStr` (or `struct myStr`, it does not matter) based on `someOtherData`, then I updated some values to the next `struct myStr` and reordered the next `struct myStr` into the array so it is sorted and then I looped until the end.

I get pretty good complexity on this with C because sorting takes O(nlogn) and reordering takes: O(1) to find the next myStr and O(logn) to reorder this specific element to the array.

I am having problems modeling this into SML.

First of all, I started doing this with lists, but I need to change a value each time. So I started thinking of refs and arrays (I know its not the best thing).

I thought of the following in ML, using types:

```
type myStr = { 
    someData : int, 
    someOtherData : myOtherType,
    next : myStr ref, 
    prev :  myStr ref
}
```

But that does not work in ML, thus producing the following error:

```
stdIn:1.56-1.61 Error: unbound type constructor: myStr                                      
stdIn:1.38-1.43 Error: unbound type constructor: myStr
```

The basic problem is that I want to access the next element (which is not the next element in array) quickly (like in C). The idea above with the type does not work in SML.

What should I do for the above type to work, or is there any other idea modeling my data properly so I can get what I want?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say "does not work"? Do you get an error message? If so, which one?

Comment: Added the error above after the type definition in ml. Here it is 
stdIn:1.56-1.61 Error: unbound type constructor: myStr                                      
stdIn:1.38-1.43 Error: unbound type constructor: myStr.

But i strongly believe that even if there is a way to define this type its not the best way to do it in this style of programming.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently type aliases (which you define using the `type` keyword) can't be recursive in SML. To define a recursive type you'll need to define an algebraic data type using the `datatype` keyword. That way your code could be made to compile like this:

```
datatype myStr = MyStr of
  { 
    someData : int, 
    someOtherData : myOtherType,
    next : myStr ref, 
    prev :  myStr ref
  }
```

That said this definition is still very problematic. Specifically it does not allow for finite (i.e. non-circular list). Also you won't be able to define any non-recursive values of this type (though if you only intend to represent circular lists, it's only natural that the values would need to be recursive).

I assume your C version of this code represents non-circular lists by letting the last node's next pointer (and the first node's prev pointer) be null. The problem with that is that `ref`s in ML can't be null, so you can't use the same system in ML. So if you need non-circular lists, you'll need to add an explicit `Empty` value that you can use instead of `null`:

```
datatype myStr = MyStr of
  { 
    someData : int, 
    someOtherData : myOtherType,
    next : myStr ref, 
    prev :  myStr ref
  }
  | Empty
```

PS: You said that this is an assignment, but you didn't really say what exactly the assignment is asking you to do. If the assignment is for SML and it is not specifically asking you to use `ref`s/mutation, I'd assume that you're supposed to solve your problem without mutation, so you'd need to think of a different approach.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. My C code in fact is a circular list.
Well the assignment is like this. Given a circular road with discrete positions and finite runners, i read from a file each runners position and speed (two runnners cant have the same starting position). All runners run to the same direction (left or right) and  if a runner catches the runner in from of him the runner in front of him is disqualified. We are asked to print the runners that are disqualified with the order they are disqualified.

Comment: Nit: Instead of adding `Empty`, making `next` and `prev` option refs might be the preferable solution.

Comment: I ll try that too thanks for the info. Btw how can i access for example  "someData" of a stored variable c1 : myStr for example?